# jQuery and RegEx: Getting range of numbers as input

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I creating a web application, where I need to get a range of numbers as input:

Ex: 1-10, 0-100 etc.

The following is the code I use to get the range into variable "s" and display it. And #ucode is the ID of the textbox I use to get the input.

```
//JavaScript
function validate() {
    var i = $("#ucode").val(); //input
    i = i.replace(/ /,'');
    var constraint = /([0-9]+[,-])?[0-9]+$/;
    if(!constraint.test(i))
    {
        alert("Invalid Expression");
        return;
    }
    var a = i.split(","); //split and array
    var s = "";           //output string
    if(a != "")
    {
        for(n = 0; n < a.length; ++n )
        {
            var conh = /^[0-9]-[0-9]$/;
            var conc = /^[0-9]+$/;
            if(conh.test(a[n]))
            {
                var range = a[n].split("-");
                var ll = parseInt(range[0]);   //lower limit
                var ul = parseInt(range[1]);   //upper limit
                if(ul < ll) { alert("Invalid Expression"); return; }
                for(m = ll; m <= ul; ++m)
                    s += " " + m;
            }
        }
        alert(s); // Alert output
    }
}
```

The problem is this function works for range 1-9 not beyond that

if I give 1-9, it displays

`1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`

if i give 1-2,5-9, it displays

`1 2 5 6 7 8 9`

But if I give beyond 9 i.e. 1-10 or 5-45 it shows a `blank` Alert Message.

Where am I wrong? Please Help Me
Thanks in advance

Comment: This check fails when I use 1-10: `if(conh.test(a[n]))`- due to that, the s variable is empty when you alert it. What is this supposed to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I thank @NullPointer for Idea, and @Jeff to where to use it.

The problem was at the `if()` condition. So I changed the code as follows and it works fine.

```
var conh = /^[0-9]+-[0-9]+$/; //Now it matches any number of digits.
if(conh.test(a[n]))
{
  .
  :
}
```

Now it works fine. Thanks friends.

Answer (score 1):

because it's like

```
[0-9]   Find any digit from 0 to 9
```

Try somethinkg like

```
[0-9]|[0-9][0-9]
```

Check
    http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html
and
    http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html

Comment: I don't think that is the problem here, correct me if am wrong. But the `[0-9]` is for validating that user has given only the Digits not other characters. I split the expression, say `0-45` to `ll = 0` and `ul = 45` and then loop from `m = 0 to 45`.

Comment: Sorry but can you explain where I use it?

Comment: @GopikrishnaS sorry for what ?

Comment: "Sorry" is for not getting you correctly. Now Where I have to use the above mentioned expression in my code; a line number would be helpful. Also please tell me whats wrong.

Comment: No need to answer the above comment. Thanks  a lot and to @Jeff too. I got it. The answer below.